# Register_hook with respect to a subtensor of a tensor

Tags: pytorch

Assuming that we would like to modify gradients only of a part of the variable values, is it possible to register_hook in pytorch only to a subtensor (of a tensor that is a pytorch variable)?

Comment: What does subtensor mean ? A slice of the tensor ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can make a function where we modify the part of the tensor as follows:

```
def gradi(module):
    module[1]=0

h = net.param_name.register_hook(gradi)
```